# Join pandas row with column

Tags: python, pandas

I have this row dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'make':'toyota', 'model':'yaris'}, index=[0])
df

    make    model
0   toyota  yaris
```

And have this other column dataframe:

```
df_prices = pd.DataFrame({'prices':[1,2,3,4]})
df_prices

    prices
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4
```

And I would like to join them to obtain:

```
    make    model   prices
0   toyota  yaris   1
1   toyota  yaris   2
2   toyota  yaris   3
3   toyota  yaris   4
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
df=df_prices.join(df).ffill()
print(df)
```

---

```
   prices    make  model
0       1  toyota  yaris
1       2  toyota  yaris
2       3  toyota  yaris
3       4  toyota  yaris
```

If care about columns:

```
df=df[['make','model','prices']]
print(df)
```

---

```
     make  model  prices
0  toyota  yaris       1
1  toyota  yaris       2
2  toyota  yaris       3
3  toyota  yaris       4
```

**`join` + `ffill`!!!**

**Update (thanks to @larsr's comment):**

```
df=df.join(df_prices, how='outer').ffill()
print(df)
```

Would do it, and also fix column orders.

Comment: or just `df.join(df_prices, how='outer').ffill()`

Answer (score 0):

What about this,

```
print pd.merge(df,df_prices,left_index=True,right_index=True,how='outer').fillna(method='ffill')
```

Python 3:

```
print(pd.merge(df,df_prices,left_index=True,right_index=True,how='outer').fillna(method='ffill'))
```

For more specific,

```
print pd.concat([df,df_prices],axis=1).ffill()
```

Output:

```
     make  model  prices
0  toyota  yaris       1
1  toyota  yaris       2
2  toyota  yaris       3
3  toyota  yaris       4
```